# Layered naviagtion Not working in Magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, layered-navigation, magento-2.1.7

I have created some custom attribute and try to enable, these attribute are layered navigation. I follow this [document](http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/navigation-layered-filterable-attributes.html)

but, its not works for me.

I tried, `Reindex`, `Clear Cache` and `Static content generation`.

Suggest Me, How to fix this issue. or suggest me How to write custom layered navigation.

**Note:** I am using Magento 2.1.7.

Comment: try to add products with different values of your attribute, because magento hide filters which cannot reduce search results count.

Comment: @Max I added 1000 products with different values and  I choosed filter with no result option, so its need to show with out result